# Kotlin - force failing deserialization from json to class, when a non null property not exits in the json?

Tags: kotlin, gson

Assuming we have this class:

```
  class Test(@SerializedName("Nullablefield")
             val nullable: Int?,
             @SerializedName("NonNullableField")
             val nonNullable: Int)
```

And we recive this json:

```
{
    "Nullablefield": 3
}
```

As you can see, NonNullableField is missing in the json,

When using Gson().fromJson method the property becomes null (even though the property is defined as non null one)

I read about gson using unsafe approach while doing this.

Is there a way to make the deserialization process fail in this case, with Gson or any other library?

I do not want to solve it by assigning a default value to the field.

Comment: try to set default value

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I don't want a default value. I just want it to fail.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try another deserialization library, for instance one that is actually written with Kotlin support in mind (Moshi, Jackson).
EDIT: I actually use Jackson and I think that behavior you request is default there. Anyway, I'd give a shot to moshi, it's pretty new and I think it was written in Kotlin (or at least with an extensive Kotlin support), but don't know anything about the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) library for parsing json

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi

fun main() {
    val json = """
{
    "Nullablefield": 3
}        
    """.trimIndent()
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val adapter = moshi.adapter(Test::class.java)
    val test = adapter.fromJson(json)//will crash
    println(test)
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Test(
    @Json(name = "Nullablefield")
    val nullable: Int?,
    @Json(name = "NonNullableField")
    val nonNullable: Int
)
```